# error in dependency array, post method does not work in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks

My hook is displaying the following message: **The 'init' object makes the dependencies of useCallback Hook (at line 28) change on every render. Move it inside
the useCallback callback. Alternatively, wrap the initialization of 'init' in its own useMemo() Hook**

I used useCallback, but it didn't solve the problem. I need to use Get and Post methods. Can someone help me?

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const useHttp = url => {
  const [body, setBody] = useState(null)
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [method, setMethod] = useState('get');

  const init = {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }

  body ? setBody(JSON.stringify(body)) : setBody({})

  const http = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(url, body, init)
      .then(res => {
        const message = "Ops! There was an error. Check connection or report to Admin";
        if (!res.ok) return Promise.reject(message);
      })
      .then(setData)
      .catch(setError)
      .finally(setLoading(false))
  }, [url, body, init])
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    http()
  }, [http]);

  return { data, error, loading, setBody, setMethod };
}

export default useHttp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very highly recommend just using the [use-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-http) or [axios-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks) libraries if you need those in a hook. Then you aren't trying to re-create the wheel.

If you must create your own hook, I see quite a few problems.

1. `body ? setBody(JSON.stringify(body)) : setBody({})` --- Just set the initial state to `{}` for `body` and remove this line - you definitely do not want to set state directly in the component, plus this would create an infinite loop.
2. If you're going to use a callback, then `init` should literally be placed inside the `useCallback` above your `fetch` - then you remove `init` as a dependency and add `method` as a dependency.
3. You're using a `useEffect` that runs the `http` method is effectively doing nothing with the `useCallback`.

You should decide if the hook will hit the `useFetch` method as soon as it's instantiated in a component? Or when all of the required parameters are set. Recreating a nicely working `axios`/`fetch` hook is not going to be simple and will have many bugs as you find different needs for how you call your endpoints in your app.

I recommend checking out [Building Your Own Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and when to use the [React useCallback()](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useCallback)